# Como usar os caracteres especiais em strings?

Tags: c#, asp.net, string

Para que servem os caracteres `~` e `@` na string do *path* em ASP.NET. Exemplo:

```
StreamReader srFile = new StreamReader(@"\\server\pasta\arquivo.html");
```

Comment: O problema não tem relação com ASP.NET. Editei para melhorar isso mas mantive em parte para deixar sua intenção original. Você poderia citar um exemplo usando o ~. Aí você verá que não tem relação com o problema ou vai mostrar que sua dúvida  com esse caractere é outra. Tente deixar mais claro para receber melhores respostas.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

No path do ASP.NET você possui alguns 'atalhos' para especificar o caminho.

Vamos supor que seu projeto está no seguinte caminho
`C:\Projetos\TestandoOPath`

E você vai utilizar o código na página que está no `http://localhost:<porta>/TestandoOPath/Pagina/Teste/index.aspx`

Você pode utilizar as seguintes opções:

- Server.MapPath("."): retorna o diretório físico do arquivo que está executando essa operação no caso `C:\Projetos\TestandoOPath\Pagina\Teste`
- Server.MapPath(".."): retorna um diretório anterior ao atual no caso `C:\Projetos\TestandoOPath\Pagina`
- Server.MapPath("~"): retorna a raiz da aplicação no caso `C:\Projetos\TestandoOPath`

E o uso do `@` é para tratar o texto sem o [efeito de caracteres de escape](https://pt.wikipedia.org/wiki/Caractere_de_escape).

Exemplo: `new StreamReader(@"\server\pasta\arquivo.html");`se você **não** colocar o `@` você precisa colocar outro `\` ficando `"\\server\\pasta\\arquivo.html"` para anular o efeito de escape dele.

Mais informaçãos sobre os 'atalhos' no path pode ser visto [aqui no SO inglês](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/275781/server-mappath-server-mappath-server-mappath-server-mappath/275791#275791).

Answer (score 2):

O simbolo `@`, antes duma string literal, serve para evitar *escapar* os caracteres especiais da string.

```
@"\server\pasta\arquivo.html"
```

é equivalente a :

```
"\\server\\pasta\\arquivo.html"
```

O símbolo `@` também pode ser usado para usar keywords como nome de variáveis:

```
int class; //erro de compilação, a palavra "class" esta reservada
int @class; //funciona
```

O operador `~` é o complemento de um (ou negação *bitwise*). Serve para negar todos os bits.

```
~ 1001 = 0110
```

Links: [One's complement operator](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/dxt4z71k.aspx) / [Complemento de um](http://digital.ni.com/public.nsf/allkb/F2726B2EDAAD0375862576C4004D3BCC)